# HTML: Is this acceptable? I wrapped an <h4> around text and a select

Tags: html

I'm trying to do something and I know using < br> isn't a good way of putting stuff on a new line so I was told to try H1-6's so I did but it instead made my answer and question on two different lines but if I do it like this

```
        <div>
            <label for="room">Select Your Room:</label>
            <select id="room" name="room" required>
                <option disabled selected value="">
                    Choose a room
                </option>
                <option value="S308">
                    S308
                </option>
                <option value="S324">
                    S324
                </option>
                <option value="L2">
                    L2
                </option>
                <option value="ME201">
                    ME201
                </option>
                <option value="ME208">
                    ME208
                </option>
        </div>
        <div>
            </select> <br>
            <label for="machinenum">Select Your Machine Number:</label>
            <label for="machinenum">1 - 15 </label>
            <input id="machinenum" name="machinenum" type="number" min="1" max="15" value="1" required><br>
        </div>
```

Then it works fine the outcome is like this: [image]
instead of being like this: [image]
or even without the h4 then having all questions stick together.

Answer (score 0):

why not like this?

```
<div id="room">
  <div>
    <label for="room">Select Your Room:</label>
    <select id="room" name="room" required>    
    <option disabled selected value="">Choose a room</option>
    <option value="S308">S308</option>
    <option value="S324">S324</option>
    <option value="L2">L2</option>
    <option value="ME201">ME201</option>
    <option value="ME208">ME208</option>
  </div> 
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: This just comes out like this when I do it for all of the others as well http://prnt.sc/cxiz1l

Comment: you can use css to adjust the margin or padding of each element

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS for this:

```
your-selector-with-heading-and-input {
    display: inline-block
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sxLyox0e/

And you also should use label for the select heading and style the font size via CSS

Comment: I edited my original post with more code. But as for the CSS I tried that and I was told that " The ids are not necessary and if I were going to use some type of custom selector it would be a class so that I could repeat it multiple times on the page."

Comment: I don't see two "id"s?

Comment: oh I removed the div name as it was impractical to use a div id for every single thing, I'm stuck now though

Comment: Your fiddle is just for using #room tag I dont wanna give IDs to all of my different things

Comment: Just updated it, you can use div or any class also ... thats basic CSS